# Swagger - Custom authentication for /api-docs

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

We have have a Spring 5, non-Spring Boot application, using Springfox 2.9.2 + Swagger UI.

I don't know how to secure /api-docs endpoint: I'd like it to call my authentication function each time it's accessed. I made it work for swagger-ui.html, but without success for /api-docs. Here's what I got.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    protected AuthService authService;


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        // registry.addViewController("/docs/swagger/api-docs"); doesnt work
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/docs/swagger/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/docs/swagger/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/docs/swagger/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
    }

    class Interceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler ) {
            try{
                authService.assertAdmin(); // I need to call this
            }catch (Exception e){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors( final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new Interceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // docs/swagger/index.html
        registry.addResourceHandler("/docs/swagger/swagger-ui.html**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");

        // docs/swagger/webjars
        registry.addResourceHandler("/docs/swagger/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Another option would be to close access to /api-docs permanently and just directly call the method that generates JSON from some new endpoint. Would that be possible?

Comment: Why don't you use `Spring-Security` to secure the endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved this by spring security, as @UsamaAmjad proposed.

```
open class SecurityInitializer : AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer()

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {


    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.antMatcher("/docs/swagger/v2/api-docs").addFilter(myFilter())
    }

    open fun myFilter() = object : FilterSecurityInterceptor() {
        override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest?, response: ServletResponse?, chain: FilterChain?) {

            if (do your stuff here) {
                chain!!.doFilter(request,response) // continue with other filters
            } else {
                super.doFilter(request, response, chain) // filter this request
            }
        }
    }
}
```